# Multisite: setting theme and options when a new blog is created

Tags: themes, options, activation, customization

When a new blog is created in a WP Multisite instance I want to be able to set the default theme and configuration options

- create 2 menus (main and secondary) and associate them with the 2 slots provided by the theme
- set various theme options as defined on the theme option page

What's the best way to go about achieving this?

- which hook should i use - I'm going to use this: ('WP_DEFAULT_THEME', 'theme-folder-name' in wp-config.php to set the default theme - unless this prevents a needed hook from firing.
- easiest way to programatically create menus and associate them with existing theme menu 'slots'

Comment: anyone got anything here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best hook I can find is `wpmu_new_blog` (line 1086, `wp-includes/ms-functions.php`, `wpmu_create_blog()`) - it passes 6 arguments like so;

```
do_action( 'wpmu_new_blog', $blog_id, $user_id, $domain, $path, $site_id, $meta );
```

`$meta` is an array of initial site options, not to be confused with the options generated by `populate_options()`.

Programatically creating nav menus may prove to be a little tricky, as there is no 'API' as such - they're a mix of posts, post meta and `nav_menu` terms, coupled with a few available functions such as `is_nav_menu_item()` and `wp_setup_nav_menu_item()`.

My best advice would be to check out `wp-admin/nav-menus.php`, as this is where all the core code lies for creating menus.

Using `WP_DEFAULT_THEME` should be fine, and is probably the best approach too.

Comment: For future reference, the hook `wpmu_new_blog` was deprecated in WordPress 5.1 and replaced with `wp_insert_site`. It is not a direct replacement, however, as the new hook receives a `WP_Site` instance now. Here's the [notice](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wpmu_new_blog/) and [here's an example of how one plugin add support for the change](https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/pull/12320/files#diff-b77e38465f872c257610ba853807a43eL529).

Answer (score 5):

This is a little late, but I had to figure out the other part of this question on my own and thought I would share.

To create a default menu and place it into a theme location, you will need a pre-existing location in the theme, and you will need to ensure any pages you link in your menu are also created already.

In your theme's function.php, register any menu locations. I registered two:

```
function my_register_navs() {
    register_nav_menus(
        array( 'header-menu' => __( 'Header Menu' )
        , 'footer-menu' => __( 'Footer Menu' ) )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_register_navs' );
```

Next, you will need to create your menus on site creation.  I didn't use a hook for this, but instead called `wpmu_create_blog` manually, but you could hook into `wpmu_new_blog` if you preferred.

```
// Create the menus
$hdr_menu = array(
    'menu-name'     => 'Header Menu'
    , 'description' => 'The primary navigation menu for this website'
);
$header_menu = wp_update_nav_menu_object( 0, $hdr_menu );

$ftr_menu = array(
    'menu-name'     => 'Footer Menu'
    , 'description' =>  'The menu that appears at the bottom of most pages in this website'
);
$footer_menu = wp_update_nav_menu_object( 0, $ftr_menu );

// Set the menus to appear in the proper theme locations
$locations = get_theme_mod('nav_menu_locations');
$locations['header-menu'] = $header_menu;
$locations['footer-menu'] = $footer_menu;
set_theme_mod('nav_menu_locations', $locations);
```

Lastly, you'll need to add items to the menus.  Repeat this code for each item in each menu.

```
// Build menu item
$menu_item = array(
    'menu-item-object-id'       => $page_id
    , 'menu-item-parent-id'     => 0
    , 'menu-item-position'      => $menu_order
    , 'menu-item-object'        => 'page'
    , 'menu-item-type'          => 'post_type'
    , 'menu-item-status'        => 'publish'
    , 'menu-item-title'         => $label
);

// Add to nav menu
wp_update_nav_menu_item( $header_menu, 0, $menu_item );
```

Hope this helps! Here are some external references for you:

- [get_theme_mod](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_theme_mod)
- [wp_update_nav_menu_item](http://www.acousticwebdesign.net/wordpress/how-to-create-wordpress-3-navigation-menus-in-your-theme-or-plugin-code/) This blog has a good example of creating menu items

Answer (score 0):

```
function mysite_wpmu_new_blog($blog_id)
{
    switch_to_blog($blog_id);
    switch_theme('my-theme', 'my-theme');
    restore_current_blog();
}

add_action('wpmu_new_blog', 'mysite_wpmu_new_blog');
```

This works for me!