# WordPress network: set themes and plugins for new blog

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, multisite, customization, network-admin

How can I enable specific themes and plugins for new blogs that have been created with [`wpmu_create_blog`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpmu_create_blog)? I'd like to set the themes and plugins in code rather than having a person manually set them in the network administration section (i.e. not in `http://domain/wp-admin/network/site-themes.php?id=xx`).

Thanks!

Update: Actually I think I may have figured **part** of this out. [`wpmu_create_blog`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpmu_create_blog) has a `$meta` property. This property can be set to an associative array with a key of 'allowedthemes'. That key's value should be set to an associative array with keys:values = 'theme-name-or-id':true. I still need to set the starting theme for this blog and set plugins, which must be similar. Is this even a good approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This WPSE answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12204/multisite-setting-theme-and-options-when-a-new-blog-is-created) led me to the $meta argument for `wpmu_create_blog`. That led me to this [Support thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wpmu_new_blog-not-firing-if-not-logged-in?replies=5) showing that $meta can include `template` and `stylesheet` arguments which seem to contain the folder name for the theme you want (just like the "Template" field in a child theme's style.css head section).

I'm having a hard time finding good documentation on `wpmu_create_blog`, but hopefully this is enough to work on.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to assign template and stylesheet to a sub site/blog:

```
// create the blog
$blog_ID = wpmu_create_blog( $domain, $path, $title, 1 );

// assign template and stylesheet to the blog
update_blog_option( $blog_ID, 'template', 'your_template_name' );
update_blog_option( $blog_ID, 'stylesheet', 'your_stylesheet_name' );
```

This will assign the template and stylesheet to the blog that has been just created. Please visit the following link to see the documentation for wpmu_create_blog function.

[wpmu_create_blog](https://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/wpmu_create_blog)

Many thanks.

Comment: I gave the answer to @mrwweb because his answer was written first, but thanks for writing code.

Answer (score 0):

```
function mysite_wpmu_new_blog($blog_id)
{
    switch_to_blog($blog_id);
    switch_theme('my-theme', 'my-theme');
    restore_current_blog();
}

add_action('wpmu_new_blog', 'mysite_wpmu_new_blog');
```

This works for me!

Comment: No need to post _exactly_ the same answer two times.

Comment: sorry, i just want to make sure people do not miss the answers they need.